# Регулярное выражение с заменой

Tags: php

Нужно заменить все встречающиеся точки кроме таких случаев:

```
рис.
г.
табл.
```

Делаю так:

```
#([^\sрис.\s][^\sг.\s][^\sтабл.\s][.])#u
```

В итоге не заменяются кроме нужных еще и сочетания ри. та. абл.
И так далее.
Как сделать чтобы [^\sрис.\s] охватывало именно сочетания символов рис.
а не ри. ис.
Модификатор \w+  вроде не поможет или я не знаю куда его ставить.

Comment: круглые скобки. не квадратные

Answer (score 0):

Для наглядности, все необходимые точки будут заменены на тире "-":

```
$str = 'Нужно.заменить..все...встречающиеся. точки .кроме таких случаев: рис. г. табл.';

$str = preg_replace('~(?<!рис|г|табл)\.~', '-', $str);

var_dump($str);
```

---

Результат:

```
Нужно-заменить--все---встречающиеся- точки -кроме таких случаев: рис. г. табл.
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо!

Comment: @Александр если мой ответ является решением вашего вопроса, отметьте его галочкой.